# What is the best way to have an AWS Canary log to a database instead of an S3 Bucket?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to set up canaries to monitor uptime of my website. As far as I can tell canaries are designed to log results of each run to a text file in an S3 bucket. This isn't ideal for doing any analytics on the monitoring data.

What would be the best way to get a canary to insert a row into a MySQL database hosted in AWS using RDS instead of writing to S3?

I suppose I could just create a lambda when files are written to the bucket, parse the JSON log files, and import them into the database, but this seems a very roundabout way to accomplish logging to a DB instead of S3

Answer (score 0):

CloudWatch canaries log to [AWS CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html), not to an S3 bucket. For performing analytics you may want to look at using [AWS CloudWatch Logs Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AnalyzingLogData.html).

Comment: When I configure the canary I have to specify an S3 bucket and files appear there when it is running. Am I missing something?

Comment: I just went back to look at the documentation to make sure we were talking about the same thing. I'm assuming you are using CloudWatch Synthetics canaries? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Synthetics_Canaries.html If that's the case, then you are running a Lambda function which will send its logs to AWS CloudWatch Logs. However there will also be result files, such as screenshots, that are copied to an S3 bucket.

Comment: From the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Synthetics_artifact_encryption.html "CloudWatch Synthetics stores canary artifacts such as screenshots, HAR files, and reports in your Amazon S3 bucket. " Those aren't runtime logs, those are output files generated by y our script.